# setting onClickListener on listView that is populated with json

Tags: android, json, listview

i have implemented a multi colum list view that is populated from json data. i also have set an onClickListener to it. but on running the app when i click the listView i am only able to fetch the first item of the list.

what i want to acheive is when i click on any item in the listView i should be able to get the row item. the code that i used is as follows

Adapter.java

```
private Activity activity;
private static ArrayList prefrenceid,partnerid;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public CompanyRegistrationAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList pref, ArrayList part) {
    activity = a;
    this.prefrenceid = pref;
    this.partnerid=part;


    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return prefrenceid.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.company_registation_adapter, null);

    TextView preferences = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView20);
    String song = prefrenceid.get(position).toString();
    preferences.setText(song);


    TextView partner = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView21);
    String song2 = partnerid.get(position).toString();
    partner.setText(song2);

    return vi;

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
AsyncHttpClient usercheck = new AsyncHttpClient();
    usercheck.get("REST URL", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            try {
                progressDialog.hide();
                JSONObject obj3 = new JSONObject(response);
                final JSONArray jsonArray3 = obj3.getJSONArray("REST Method");
                int length3 = jsonArray3.length();
                if (length3 != 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < length3; i++) {
                        JSONObject user3 = jsonArray3.getJSONObject(i);
                        preference_array.add(user3.getString("GCP_NUMBER").toString());
                        partner_array.add(user3.getString("COMPANY_NAME").toString());
                    }
                    adapter = new CompanyRegistrationAdapter(CompanyRegistrationResult.this, preference_array, partner_array);
                    fav.setAdapter(adapter);
                    fav.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            try {
                                String iPartnerID = jsonArray3.getJSONObject(position).getString("ID");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),iPartnerID,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent compRegister=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CompanyRegistration.class);
                                compRegister.putExtra("gcp", gcp);
                                compRegister.putExtra("compName", compName);
                                startActivity(compRegister);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String gcp=((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView20)).getText().toString();
                            String compName=((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21)).getText().toString();

                        }
                    });

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: In your getItem method in the adapter, you are returning simply the int that is the index of the clicked item, not the actual item. You should do preferenceid.get(position);

Comment: Why dont you get it from the model... preference_array.get(position).toString() its the same value you put on the textview...

Comment: thanks a lot Fustigador and Nanoc. i got it working..